# AngularJs unit test - function called after promise resolved

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to test if my service call was successfull and if the function "search" was called after the service call.

My Controller:

```
function UnitTestsCtrl(homePSrv, $scope) {
    var that = this;
    this.SearchModel = {};
    this.homePSrv = homePSrv;
}

UnitTestsCtrl.prototype.Init = function() {
     var that = this;
    this.homePSrv.InitUnitTestSearchModel().then(function(result) {
        that.SearchModel = result;
        that.Search();
    });
}

angular.module("unitTestsCtrl", [])
       .controller("unitTestsCtrl", UnitTestsCtrl);
```

The jasmine unit test:

```
describe('Controller Tests: "UnitTestsCtrl"', function () {
    var ctrl, mockHomePSrv;

    beforeEach(function () {
        mockHomePSrv = jasmine.createSpyObj('homePSrv', ['InitUnitTestSearchModel']);
        module('app.main');

        inject(function ($controller, $q) {

            mockHomePSrv.InitUnitTestSearchModel.and.returnValue($q.when('InitUnitTestSearchModelData'));

            ctrl = $controller('unitTestsCtrl', {
                homePSrv: mockHomePSrv,
            });
        });
    });

  it('Funktion "Search" was called', function () {
        spyOn(ctrl, 'Init');
        spyOn(ctrl, 'Search');
        ctrl.Init();
        expect(ctrl.Init).toHaveBeenCalled();

        //Thats not working - its not being called
        expect(ctrl.Search).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
});
```

The problem is that the expectation if the search function was called is false. I think it has to do with the promise.

Solution:

```
 spyOn(ctrl, 'Search');
 ctrl.Init();
 $scope.$digest()   //I've inserted this and everything works fine now
 expect(ctrl.Init).toHaveBeenCalled();
 expect(ctrl.Search).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Could you try adding a `$rootScope.digest()` before the `expect` call that is not working? I believe Angular's `$q` is synchronized to the digest cycle. You will have to import the `$rootScope` of course. Alternatively, you can supply a mock promise, i.e. instead of `.and.returnValue($q.when(...))`, do `.and.returnValue({then: function(){...}})`, where the given function will capture its argument and make it available to your code to run.

Comment: I've added $scope.$digest() bevore the expect and that works fine now